# How to persist enums as ordinals with Spring Boot and Cassandra?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, enums, cassandra

To the enum field of my entity I have added `@CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.INT)`. However not the ordinal of the enum, but the string representation instead, is used in the statement sent to Cassandra. Thus I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: SessionCallback; CQL [INSERT INTO thing (thing_id,some_enum) VALUES (1,'Foo');]; Expected 4 or 0 byte int (3); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 4 or 0 byte int (3)
```

Below you can find a minimal example, reproducing the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

### `test/src/main/kotlin/enumtest/Application.kt`

```
package enumtest

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication


@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

### `test/src/main/kotlin/enumtest/SomeEnum.kt`

```
package enumtest


enum class SomeEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar
}
```

### `test/src/main/kotlin/enumtest/Thing.kt`

```
package enumtest

import com.datastax.driver.core.DataType
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraType
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table


@Table("thing")
@Suppress("unused")
class Thing(

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "thing_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    var thingId: Long,

    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.INT)
    @Column("some_enum")
    var someEnum: SomeEnum

)
```

### `test/src/main/kotlin/enumtest/ThingRepository.kt`

```
package enumtest

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
interface ThingRepository : CassandraRepository<Thing, Long>
```

### `test/src/main/resources/application.yml`

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      contact-points: localhost
      port: 9142
      keyspace_name: enumtest
```

### `test/src/test/kotlin/enumtest/PersistenceTest.kt`

```
package enumtest

import org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraDataSet
import org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraUnitDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener
import org.cassandraunit.spring.EmbeddedCassandra
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner

@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestExecutionListeners(
    listeners = [CassandraUnitDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener::class],
    mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS
)
@CassandraDataSet(value = ["cql/cassandra_schema.cql"], keyspace = "enumtest")
@EmbeddedCassandra
class PersistenceTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var thingRepository: ThingRepository

    @Test
    fun `test save`() {
        thingRepository.save(Thing(1, SomeEnum.Foo))
        val things = thingRepository.findAll()
        Assert.assertEquals(1, things.size)
        val thing = things[0]
        Assert.assertEquals(SomeEnum.Foo, thing.someEnum)
    }
}
```

### `test/src/test/resources/cql/cassandra_schema.cql`

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT exists enumtest
WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};

CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists enumtest.thing (
    thing_id     bigint,
    some_enum    int,
    PRIMARY KEY (thing_id)
);
```

### `test/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.30'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.3.30'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repository.apache.org/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect'

    testImplementation group: 'org.cassandraunit', name: 'cassandra-unit-spring', version: '3.5.0.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```

---

Here is the full version of the minimal example as a download to faciliate experimentation: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zzIDhbWycaj4WXrze2sAmw8xRPacA8Js

Edit: Since it seems to be a bug, I just opened [a Jira issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-652).

Comment: I'm not sure about Spring, but you can do following in Java driver: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#enums

Comment: @AlexOtt Thanks for the hint. However I did not yet get it working. My `PersistenceTest.kt` now looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/9bf5c7ea3d52515cad0e97c5fa480d0d), but the error is still the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say - it looks like a problem inside Spring... Do you really need to use Spring, and not use Object Mapper from Java driver?

Comment: also, things like, `findAll` are very bad for Cassandra, and you'll start to get problems as soon as your data grow enough...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'd very much like to use Spring Boot for consistency with other microservices of our fleet. And yes, I know about `findAll`. I only use it for the tests in this minimal example.

Comment: would it be fair to say there's a performance benefit to saving it as an ordinal?

Comment: Likely, yes. But in case of doubt, always measure your own use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to get this working for quite awhile and it seems I finally got it!

I was running into the same issue you were with the codec...I have no idea why that's not working. According to their documentation you were doing it exactly right.

So I implemented my own Cassandra Write Converter. See below

```
@Configuration
class CassandraConfig(val cluster: Cluster){

    @Bean
    fun setCustomCassandraConversions() = CassandraCustomConversions(listOf(EnumWriteConverter.INSTANCE, EnumReadConverter.INSTANCE))

    @WritingConverter
    enum class EnumWriteConverter : Converter<Enum<MyEnum>, Int> {
        INSTANCE;
        override fun convert(source: Enum<MyEnum>) = source.ordinal
    }
     @ReadingConverter
    enum class EnumReadConverter : Converter<Int, Enum<MyEnum>> {
        INSTANCE;
        override fun convert(source: Int) = MyEnum.values()[source]
    }
}
```

This should on every write you do to Cassandra convert all enums it sees of type MyEnum to an Int using the overridden converter. This opens you up to the possibility of having multiple of these for different types of Enums where maybe for some reason you would like to write other custom values from them instead of always converting all enums.

Hope this works!

***EDIT***
Note the change in removing { } for INSTANCE on each converter, and registering the ReadingConverter with the CassandraCustomConversions

Comment: Thanks! Saving to Cassandra works fine after adding [CassandraConfig](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/371446dbc71aa233815442b413965901). However now the load part (`val things = thingRepository.findAll()`) fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant enumtest.SomeEnum.0`. I tried [adding](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/83630aa1ff47b2271effa607f5f0fa26) the needed `@ReadingConverter`, but to no avail. Any further ideas?

Comment: You were very close! But you forgot to register the read converter in the CassandraCustomConversions. Although....when i did this i still had an error, and fixed it by slightly changing the read and write converters as so. See edit above.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually I once had the `EnumReadConverter` also registered, just not in the version I pasted into the gist. With the registration I get `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [ANY <-> enumtest.Something]`.
Your new version, the once with `INSTANCE; ...` instead of `INSTANCE { ...`, however works perfectly.

Comment: I had the same error and when I looked a previous examples where I had done this I noticed that was the only difference. Glad it worked!

Comment: Small remark for future readers: In case one does want to persist as `tinyint` instead of `int` in Cassandra, the `@ReadingConverter` needs to be `enum class EnumReadConverter : Converter<Byte, MyEnum>` instead of `enum class EnumReadConverter : Converter<Byte, Enum<MyEnum>>`.

Answer (score 2):

This is [fixed](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-652) since Spring Boot version `2.1.5`.

However, the `@CassandraType` needs to be placed at the getter explicitly in Kotlin, because otherwise it is not seen at runtime.

In practice this simply means replacing this:

```
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.INT)
    var someEnum: SomeEnum
```

with that:

```
    @get: CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.INT)
    var someEnum: SomeEnum
```