# Kotlin Spring Boot Unit Test - adding in @TestExecutionListeners doesn't inject dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection, junit4

I'm trying to use the Flyway Test Extensions library, and one of its instructions was to add in:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, 
                         FlywayTestExecutionListener.class })
```

And so in Kotlin I have something along the lines of:

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
 @TestExecutionListeners(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener::class, 
                         FlywayTestExecutionListener::class )
 class MyControllerTest {
     @Autowired
     lateinit var dataSource : DataSource
 }
```

But for some reason, when I try to run a test in that class, I get an error saying that the lateinit property has not been initialized.

Is there something special I need to have/do in order to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to finally find 1 other post that helped me resolve it: [How to persist enums as ordinals with Spring Boot and Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55915849/how-to-persist-enums-as-ordinals-with-spring-boot-and-cassandra)

The annotation I needed was:

```
@TestExecutionListeners(
    listeners = [FlywayTestExecutionListener::class],
    mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS
)
```